# How to convert string to number in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this:

```
name <- c("a1", "c8", "c8", "ds 14m", "ms 34k", "ds 14m")
num <- c(3, 5, 6, 2, 8, 4)

df <- cbind(name, num)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
```

I want a dataset like this:

```
name2 <- c("1", "2", "2", "3", "4", "3")
df2 <- cbind(name2, num)
df2 <- as.data.frame(df2)
```

Is there a function to do the transformation of the column `name` automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using match.

```
tmp=unique(df$name)
names(tmp)=1:length(tmp)
match(df$name,tmp)
[1] 1 2 2 3 4 3
```

Using factor.

```
as.character(factor(df$name,labels=1:length(unique(df$name))))
[1] "1" "2" "2" "3" "4" "3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Coerce `as.factor` and strip off levels, i.e. `as.integer`.

```
transform(df, name=as.integer(as.factor(name)))
#   name num
# 1    1   3
# 2    2   5
# 3    2   6
# 4    3   2
# 5    4   8
# 6    3   4
```